# Pass an Object in a Quoted String in R - Bigrquery

Tags: r

I am trying to run a query with Bigrquery using an object as my between date range.  I have start.date and end.date as character objects, but they must be passed as part of a quoted string.

```
query <- paste("SELECT * FROM [dataset.table] WHERE date between",start.date," and ",end.date)
```

However, this returns the start.date and end.date objects without their necessary surrounding quotes.  I haven't been able to find a way to pass quotes in part of a paste() statement.  Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste("SELECT * FROM [dataset.table] WHERE date between \"",
       start.date,"\" and \"",end.date, "\"", sep="")
```

Comment: That is just how it prints out.     `cat(query)`   after you create it like this.